# How to filter data using class attributes with MongoTemplate?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mongotemplate

I'm using MongoTemplate for the first time.
Using Postman, I am hitting the API and passing a JSON as @RequestBody to get a filtered list of Student.

**Model Class**

> Student.java

```
package bd.ac.seu.erp.criteriademo.model;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Student {
    @Id
    String studentId;

    @NotNull
    Name name;

    String nationality;

}
```

> Name.java

```
package bd.ac.seu.erp.criteriademo.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Name {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

**Controller**

> StudentController.java

```
package bd.ac.seu.erp.criteriademo.Controller;

import bd.ac.seu.erp.criteriademo.Service.StudentService;
import bd.ac.seu.erp.criteriademo.model.Student;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

@CrossOrigin()
@RestController
public class StudentController {
    StudentService studentService;

    public StudentController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }

    @PostMapping("student/filter")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getFilteredList(@RequestBody HashMap<String, String> fieldValueMap) {
        System.out.println("Something");

        MultiValueMap<String, String> multiValueMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        multiValueMap.add("requestedBy", "Shamin Asfaq");

        List<Student> studentList = studentService.applyFilter(fieldValueMap);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(studentList, multiValueMap, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**Service**

> StudentService.java

```
package bd.ac.seu.erp.criteriademo.Service;

import bd.ac.seu.erp.criteriademo.model.Student;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class StudentService {

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
    String databaseName;

    public List<Student> applyFilter(HashMap<String,String> fieldValueMap) {

        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(new MongoClient("127.0.0.1"), databaseName);

        Query query = new Query();

        for(Map.Entry<String,String> keyValuePair: fieldValueMap.entrySet()) {
            query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(keyValuePair.getKey()).is(keyValuePair.getValue()));
        }

        return mongoTemplate.find(query, Student.class);
    }
}
```

When I am hitting the API via Postman, normally this is what I am sending as @RequestBody:

```
{
    "nationality":"Bangladeshi"
}
```

..and it's working just fine.
The problem starts when I am trying to filter data using the "firstName" or "lastName" attribute.

This is what I tried to send:

```
{
    "name": {
        "firstName": "Shamin"
    }
}
```

Thre return I am getting from Postman is:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-08-09T12:01:58.620+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 10] (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap[\"name\"])",
    "path": "/student/filter"
}
```

Clearly, I have understood that the backend is considering "name" as **key** and the rest of the portion as **value**.

How can I filter data using "firstName" or "lastName" attribute here? To be more generic, how can I filter data using class attributes or, attributes of a Class within another Class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your map is not getting deserialized properly in the rest controller. 
instead of using HashMap.

Try to use Student class as request body or use something like com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode and read the values.

```
public ResponseEntity<?> getFilteredList(@RequestBody ObjectNode req)
```

or change the Json to:

```
{
    "name.firstname":"aaa"
}
```

For your needs I think you should look at QueryDsl it is very nice and you can do queries with GET request student/filter?name.firstname=xxx, you have nice examples [link](https://www.baeldung.com/queries-in-spring-data-mongodb)

You only need to extend QuerydslPredicateExecutor in the StudentRepository:

```
import org.springframework.data.querydsl.QuerydslPredicateExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Student, String>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Student> {
}
```

and then just query using predicate:

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.querydsl.binding.QuerydslPredicate;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

@CrossOrigin()
@RestController
public class StudentController {
    StudentRepository studentService;

    public StudentController(StudentRepository studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }

    @GetMapping("student/filter")
    public ResponseEntity<Page<Student>> getFilteredList(@QuerydslPredicate(root = Student.class) Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {
        System.out.println("Something");

        MultiValueMap<String, String> multiValueMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        multiValueMap.add("requestedBy", "Shamin Asfaq");

        Page<Student> studentList = studentService.findAll(predicate, pageable);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(studentList, multiValueMap, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

you also need to add this build plugin to your pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${apt.version}</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                    <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/annotations</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        <logOnlyOnError>true</logOnlyOnError>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I've gone through two of the approaches you suggested.
Although QueryDsl seemed nicer, changing the JSON was the easier way for me to achieve what I was trying to do. Especially, because I didn't have to change any of my backends.
It's was a great help, thanks!